# Maxscript filepath read?

Tags: bitmap, shader, 3dsmax, maxscript

Hey guys i have this simple script that am testing. At the moment it basically lets you pick a bitmap and then adds the path to the edittext. The assign shader button created a materials and assigns it. What i am looking to do is use the user path to define a bitmap texture to add to the diffuse slot. Kinda stuck there. thanks for the help in advanced. here is the script so far

try(DestroyDialog Browse)catch()

Rollout Browse "Browse" width:550 height:150

(

```
button btn_browse "browse" pos:[430,20]
button btn_assin "Assign Shader "
edittext edt_image "ImageFile:" fieldWidth: 350 pos:[5,22]

on btn_browse pressed do
(
    imgDir = getOpenFilename caption: "Open File"   types: "Jpg (*.jpg)|*.jpg|Exr (*.exr)|*.exr|Tif (*.tif)|*.tif|ALL|*.*|"
    edt_image.text = imgDir

)

on btn_assin pressed do
        (   
            if edt_image != undefined do
            (   
                for i in selection do
                    (
                    i.material =  meditmaterials[1].diffuseMap = Bitmaptexture filename: ????????????????????
                    )
            )
        )
```

)

createdialog Browse

Answer (score 2):

```
try(DestroyDialog Browse) catch()
rollout Browse "Browse" width:550
(
    editText edt_image "Image File:" fieldWidth:400 across:2
    button btn_browse "Browse" align:#right
    button btn_assign "Assign Shader"

    on btn_browse pressed do
    (
        local imgPath = getOpenFilename caption: "Open File" types: "Jpg (*.jpg)|*.jpg|Exr (*.exr)|*.exr|Tif (*.tif)|*.tif|ALL|*.*|"
        if imgPath != undefined do edt_image.text = imgPath
    )

    on btn_assign pressed do if isProperty meditMaterials[1] #diffuseMap AND doesFileExist edt_image.text do
    (   
        meditMaterials[1].diffuseMap = BitmapTexture filename:edt_image.text
        selection.material = meditMaterials[1]
    )
)
createDialog Browse
```